# ImportError: No module named scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, pybrain

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to get PyBrain to work.

But I get this error even though scipy is installed -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-
py2.7.egg/pybrain/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.connections.__init__ import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.connections.full import FullConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/full.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy import reshape, dot, outer
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I have installed scipy using this command -

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

I get -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-scipy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What should I do?

Comment: `python -c 'import scipy; print(scipy)'`? `which python`? `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy      and its python 2.7.5

Comment: is there a solution without sudo?

Comment: For [Windows users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43246003/562769)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Try to install it as a python package using pip. You said you already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

Now run:

```
pip install scipy
```

I ran both and it worked on my Debian-based box.

Comment: I can't sudo...is there another solution? I don't understand what was the issue and why did that solve the problem?

Comment: @DragonSpit If you have python 3, then you need use the corresponding names: `python3-scipy` and `pip3`.

Comment: 1. reinstall scipy
2. shutdown and reopen jupyter server.
It worked for me. Thank you

Comment: You should not need to install both the Debian package and the Python package. I would favor the Distribution package unless it is out of date.

Answer (score 29):

To ensure easy and correct installation for python use pip from the get go

To install pip:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python2 get-pip.py   # for python 2.7
$ sudo python3 get-pip.py   # for python 3.x
```

To install scipy using pip:

```
$ pip2 install scipy    # for python 2.7
$ pip3 install scipy    # for python 3.x
```

Answer (score 10):

***For windows users:***

I found this solution after days. Firstly which python version you want to install?

If you want for Python 2.7 version:

STEP 1:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.4 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.5 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.6 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Link: [click[1]

Once finish installation, go to your directory.

For example my directory:

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>
pip install [where/is/your/downloaded/scipy_whl.]
```

STEP 2:

> Numpy+MKL

From same web site based on python version again:

After that use same thing again in Script folder

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>
pip3 install [where/is/your/downloaded/numpy_whl.]
```

And test it in python folder.

```
Python35>python 
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>>import scipy
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. To save some time, we can find these wheels in here http://www.silx.org/pub/wheelhouse/ :)

Answer (score 8):

I had a same problem because I installed both of python2.7 and python3. when I run program with python3 I received same error. 
I install scipy with this command and problem has been solved:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to get `scipy` in your Python environment on Windows you can get the *.whl files here:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

Remember that you need to install `numpy+mkl` before you can install `scipy`.

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

When you have downloaded the correct *.whl files just open a command prompt in the download directory and run `pip install *.whl`.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using pycharm go to settings and in project interpreter sub-tab click on "+" sign next to list and in the search bar in there search name "scipy" and install the package.

[image: scipy]

Comment: worked very well for me. Thank you (python v:3.10)

Answer (score 5):

For Windows User :
      pip install -U scipy

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to remove scipy via

```
apt-get purge scipy
```

and then to install it by

```
pip install scipy
```

If you do both then you might confuse you deb  package manager due to possibly differing versions.

Answer (score 4):

Try to install it as a python package using pip as follows

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

If you want to run a python 3.x script, install scipy by:

```
$ pip3 install scipy
Otherwise install it by:
$ pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be too basic (and perhaps assumable), but -

Fedora users can use:

`sudo dnf install python-scipy`

and then (For python3.x):

`pip3 install scipy`

or (For python2.7):

`pip2 install scipy`

Answer (score 2):

Your python don't know where you installed scipy. add the scipy path to `PYTHONPATH` and I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi.Thanks a ton but can you give me the command to do that?Linux newbie,

Comment: If you are using bash, in your bash profile file, you can add this line `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/scipy:$PYTHONPATH"`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I spelt one of the libraries wrongly when installing with pip3, which ended up all the other downloaded libaries in the same command not being installed. Just run pip3 install on them again and they should be installed from their cache.

Comment: It is better to copy the command instead of typing it, this may lead to the installation of malicious libraries/packages or some other associated errors if you misspelled a command. Better be very careful from Typosquatting and Supply Chains Vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo pip install scipy` to install the library so It cannot ask for permissions later

Answer (score 1):

in previous steps by @user5747799, it do not work directly but instead change the URL (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py) and now spicy work very well on Ubuntu 20.04

Also o follow steps to switch between version from https://www.fosslinux.com/39384/switching-between-python-2-and-3-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm

To install pip using alternative URL:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
$ sudo python2 get-pip.py.2   # for python 2.7 (or verify the result of previous step)
$ sudo python3 get-pip.py   # for python 3.x
```

To install scipy using pip:

```
$ pip2 install scipy    # for python 2.7
$ pip3 install scipy    # for python 3.x
```

in order to verify

```
$ python
```

then

```
>>> import scipy
```

with no errors to show.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing a reinstall of scipy:

```
python3 -m pip install scipy --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

for Mac run below command to install scipy

```
$ brew install scipy
$ pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

for python3 below command to install scipy

```
python3 -m pip install scipy
```