# "No module named scipy" on Windows

Tags: python, windows, scipy

In sklearn\base.py, I have the statement `from scipy import sparse`. 
I am getting this error `"no module named scipy"`.

I tried to install using `pip install scipy`, but I get so many errors:

```
libraries mkl_rt not found
openblas not found
lapack not found
no lapacl/blas resources found
```

etc.

What should I do **on Windows**?

Comment: read https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: For [Linux users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24808043/562769)

Comment: For [Mac users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58020816/562769)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the scipy wheel file from the following link

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy

Then do pip install with the Downloaded file

```
pip install <wheel-file>
```

if required , provide sudo permission

Comment: Sir, I cannot find one that supports windows!

Comment: @GeethuAlphonsaJose check wheel and python version also check 32 or 64 bit

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution after days.

Firstly which python version you want to install?

If you want for Python 2.7 version:

***STEP 1:***

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.4 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.5 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

If you want for Python 3.6 version:

> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> scipy‑0.19.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Link: [click](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Once the download finished, go to your directory.

For example my directory:

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>
pip install [where/is/your/downloaded/scipy_whl.]
```

After that installation

***STEP 2:***

> Numpy+MKL

From same web site based on python version again:

After that use same thing again in Script folder

```
cd C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts>

pip3 install [where/is/your/downloaded/numpy_whl.]
```

And test it in python folder.

```
Python35>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
```

Answer (score 2):

I face same problem when install Scipy under ubuntu. 
I had to use command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
$ sudo pip install scipy
```

on CentOS

```
$ yum install lapack-devel
$ sudo pip install scipy
```

Comment: It's bad practice to do `sudo pip install scipy` -- running PyPI packages as root is dangerous and installing Python stuff into the main site-packages dir is very bad practice (it edits your OS). Consider using virtualenv, using conda+conda envs, or installing to the home directory or similar.

Comment: @Mike Graham completely agree, but please check whom are u answering to. check his ques. it has a line "I tried to install using "pip install scipy". But when I do that, I get so many errors". i thought this would be easy thing for him for now.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` should be installed before installing `scipy`. I face this issue when I was running only with `numpy`. First install `numpy` and then install `scipy`. It worked for me.

```
pip install numpy

pip install scipy
```

It will display a message like this.

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in
>    (from scipy)

Hope this would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never successfully pip'd a scipy install, instead I have found it easier to install all the base dependencies. [Check here for your OS](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

I've never tried this on windows, but the linux installs have always worked for me.