# Mac - No module named 'scipy'

Tags: python, scipy, pip, homebrew

I've tried everything but can't get Scipy to work.

Installed Scipy via Homebrew, seemed to work fine - but then the error when trying to import it.
Uninstalled, installed via pip3, no difference.
Brew doctored, brew link (forced links for the unlinked kegs for Scipy AND python), no progress.

Running on macOS Mojave (10.14.6).
Numpy, matplotlib and much more is working fine. What am I missing here?

I have two versions of python installed, but Scipy SHOULD be installed in python3.7 (which I am using). See more below:

```
d37072:~ au341374$ brew info scipy
scipy: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Software for mathematics, science, and engineering
https://www.scipy.org
/usr/local/Cellar/scipy/1.3.0_1 (962 files, 47.3MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-09-20 at 03:39:57
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/scipy.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: swig ✔
Required: gcc ✔, numpy ✔, openblas ✔, python ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
==> Caveats
If you use system python (that comes - depending on the OS X version -
with older versions of numpy, scipy and matplotlib), you may need to
ensure that the brewed packages come earlier in Python's sys.path with:
  mkdir -p /Users/au341374/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import sys; sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/au341374/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
==> Analytics
install: 3,010 (30 days), 5,751 (90 days), 31,101 (365 days)
install_on_request: 2,070 (30 days), 3,613 (90 days), 19,312 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

-

```
d37072:~ au341374$ pip3 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.16.4)


d37072:~ au341374$ brew install scipy
Warning: scipy 1.3.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.3.0_1, run `brew reinstall scipy`
```

-

```
d37072:~ au341374$ brew link scipy
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/scipy/1.3.0_1
To relink: brew unlink scipy && brew link scipy


d37072:~ au341374$ brew link python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

-

```
d37072:~ au341374$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
  /usr/local/munki/munkiwebadmin-config
```

-

```
d37072:~ au341374$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

d37072:~ au341374$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

d37072:~ au341374$ which -a python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

d37072:~ au341374$ which -a pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

-

```
d37072:~ au341374$ pip -V
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

d37072:~ au341374$ pip3 -V
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: what's the err when you try to import scipy?

Comment: Simply: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, somehow inadvertently fixed it.
I un- and reinstalled numpy and scipy a few times to no avail.
Finally uninstalled numpy, scipy, matplotlib, ipython and jupyter so that it would let me uninstall python. Reinstalling python numpy and scipy fixed nothing.
Then, after running

```
pip3 install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

I think this did it.
Scipy and numpy are now apparently installed in

```
scipy in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.3.1)
numpy>=1.13.3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from scipy) (1.17.2)
```

Rather than in usr/local/lib/Python3.7/site-packages where a regular "pip3 install scipy" was installing it.

Now the only weird thing is that ./Library/Python/ only actually contains a folder called 2.7 and not 3.7 (no hidden folders).
I'm weirded out, but hey, it works.