# ModuleNotFoundError with pyinstaller but fine in Pycharm

Tags: python, module, exe, pyinstaller, lib

I'm trying to convert a .py project to an .exe file using the using the Auto Py To Exe which uses the pyinstaller.

Running my code inside pycharm I get no errors. Running the .exe file i'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "objectGui.py", line 6, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
    [19724] Failed to execute script objectGui
```

I've tried adding following bit of code to the conversion

```
--hidden-import scipy
```

This does not change the error I keep getting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: pip install scipy

might work for you.!!

Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808043/importerror-no-module-named-scipy might help

Comment: RUN sudo apt-get install python-scipy and pip install scipy

Comment: I have scipy installed. The script runs just fine before I try to convert it into an .exe. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227191/pyinstaller-hidden-import-not-found).

Since I worked on my project in an environment (PyCharm) I needed to type in the command in the PyCharm terminal for it to work. I also added the hidden import:

```
  --hidden-import scipy
```

to find the module and it worked!